# Modify django templates to check for values in a dict

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django template.

```
{% load custom_tags %}
<ul>
{% for key, value in value.items %}
<li> {{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I need to check for the `value` and do some modifications.

If the value is `True` , instead of value I have to print `Applied` , else if it `False` I need to print `Not Applied`.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple if-else clause here. Take a look at the [django template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/) to familiarize yourself with some of the common tags.

```
{% if value %}
  APPLIED
{% else %}
   NOT APPLIED 
{% endif %}
```

You asked how to do this as a filter... I'm not sure why, but here is it:

In your app's `templatetags` directory create a file called `my_tags.py` or something and make the contents

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def applied(value):
    if value:
        return 'Applied'
    else:
        return 'Not applied'
```

Then in your template make sure to have `{% load my_tags %}` and use the filter with `{{ value|applied }}`

Comment: How to do this using a filter

Comment: Why you need a filter to do this?

Comment: The first case is about as simple as it gets... I'm not sure how you can expect a conditional to be more elegant. I suppose a filter would lead to less code in the template, but more code overall.